# Heinken bottles.

Tags: bottling

Has anyone used these bottles and recaped them with home brew? Not sure if they use twist off caps or the regular pry-offs.

Answer (score 4):

Heineken bottles use pry-off caps and can be reused for homebrew. However, you're better off using brown glass bottles than the green Heineken bottles due to the better protection from light afforded by the brown glass.

Comment: What can brown do for you? Block unwanted light from spoiling your beer.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, I've used these - they work fine. They're pry off caps as already mentioned, but they have two problems (i) the labels are clear vinyl (at least they are here in New Zealand), and so can be difficult to peel off (you can't soak them off like paper labels); and (ii) they have the Heineken logo stamped on the bottle - kinda hard to get rid of!

I also recommend brown bottles if you can find them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use them.  Just keep them in the dark post bottling.

Depending on your style capper they might be a little tough to cap.  I remember that when I used to use a couple during a bottling session in the distant past.  I would try capping a couple empties before I bought a case of heineken.